# Hostname not resolving to IP WHM/cPanel

Tags: centos, cpanel, hostname, centos6, whm

I moved my WHM/cPanel installation to a new server. After changing the nameserver IP's and then after a little while the domains to started pointing to the new server.

However the hostname doesn't resolve to an IP address.

```
/scripts/ipcheck --verbose


IMPORTANT: Do not ignore this email.

Your hostname (xxx.example.com) could not be resolved to an
IP address. This means that /etc/hosts is not set up correctly,
and/or there is no dns entry for xxx.example.com. Please be
sure that the contents of /etc/hosts are configured correctly, and
also that there is a correct 'A' entry for the domain in the zone
file.

Some or all of these problems can be caused by /etc/resolv.conf
being setup incorrectly. Please check that file if you believe
everything else is correct.

You may be able to automatically correct this problem by using the
'Add an A entry for your hostname' option under 'Dns Functions' in
your Web Host Manager.
```

I ran:

```
nano /etc/hosts


# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX         xxx.example.com xxx
```

I also check:

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Also:

```
nano /etc/nameserverips

XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX=ns1.example.com
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX=ns2.example.com
```

I checked the "Add an A Entry for your hostname" in WHM:

```
Hostname | Server Main IP
xxx.example.com | XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

I checked and rebuilt dnsconfig

```
/scripts/rebuildingdnsconfig
```

I am really not sure what else to check, i have rebooted the server. The domains pointing to the name servers work fine. THe problem i am having is i route all cpanel access and SSL configs for the emails through https://xxx.example.com because this has the SSL cert. I have compared the settings to the older server and they are the same except the IP address.

Centos 6.4
WHM 11.40.0 Build 19

- XXX.XXX.XXX = Server IPs
- xxx.example.com = hostname

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You nameserver for domain example.com are on same server? Are XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX=ns1.example.com XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX=ns2.example.com and XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX it's on your server? If you edit zona A for ("Add an A Entry for your hostname" ) but your nameserver are not on server, and not proper configured, nameserver point to other IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this:

Go to WHM, "add an entry for your hostname" and just submit again.

Even though it was correct submitting it again worked. This fix came from cPanel support.

Comment: Thank you very much Keelan! You've saved me more panic tonight at 3am. Had to migrate a few clients in the past week and noticed their sites have been offline several hours ago. Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old post, but here are a few checkpoints in addition to above if someone might need help in future with similar issue:

1> Check the content of

```
/etc/wwwacct.conf
```

2> Investigate your hostname & NS for proper results

```
dig ns1.example.com
dig hostname.exmple.com
host ns1.example.com
host (HOST IP)
nslookup hostname.exmple.com
```

3) Make sure you have registered your hostname.example.com and ns1.example.com at your domain registrar and they are pointing to right IP.

4) Ensure that no firewall is blocking port `UDP:53` and others essential ports.